# How to start Android / iOS accessory development?

Tags: android, ios, hardware, accessory

I am trying to get involved with programming accessories to interface with either Android or iOS devices. I'm a programmer with no computer engineering / electrical engineering background and am at a loss as to how to begin.

Ultimately I want to build something like this: an [ECG for the iPhone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dY7ZQM5eah8&feature=player_embedded#t=19s) or Android. What is he attaching to the iPhone? Does it connect via wifi? What type of device is it? What kind of background do I need? How do I start? Any pointers appreciated it!

I understand that things like Arduino exist that can interface with Android, but I'm not sure if that's the correct direction to go in.

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html
- http://www.amarino-toolkit.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a proprietary hardware probably using near field communication - it will be difficult to develop an electronic hardware without learning basic electronics. To start with you can get a IOIO for Android which will let you interface your phone to external hardware. It is similar to Arduin0/Amarino, but you will be at ease with it if you already know Java. As far as electronics you can start learning that as well.

Check the [official docs](http://www.github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki) to know more about IOIO.